# Difference between Authorization Code and Access Token

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest

Can you please explain the difference between authorization code, access token and bearer token? I've been looking for this on Google but didn't clear things for me. 
From REST API dev guide all I understood is that access token is something related to Username-Password authentication flow, and authorization code comes into the picture when we talking about Web-Server and user-agent flows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is good source to give you basic idea, its for FB but it works with any Oauth2
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666316/facebook-oauth-2-0-code-and-token

Answer (score 2):

An authorization code is a credential representing the resource owner's authorization (to access its protected resources) used by the client to obtain an access token. It's an intermediary construct in the authorization flow sequence, you don't need to "manage" it in your application. As you correctly pointed out, it only comes in play with specific oAuth flows such as an authorization code flow (referred to as Web Server Authentication in [Salesforce universe](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm&type=5))

Access tokens are credentials used to access protected resources. Example of a protected resource is a REST API exposed by Salesforce.

Refresh tokens are credentials used to obtain access tokens.  Refresh tokens are issued to the client by the authorization server and are used to obtain a new access token when the current access token becomes invalid or expires.

See oAuth 2.0 spec ([RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)) and the Salesforce [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm&type=5) for more details.